# Can't test local Lambda that references a DynamoDB table when using AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I created the "Quick Start: Web Backend" AWS SAM project that incudes a DynamoDB table using the `sam init sam-app`.

Following the instructions in the readme, when I try and build and invoke a lambda function that references the Dynamo table:

```
sam build
sam local invoke getAllItemsFunction --event events/event-get-all-items.json
```

I get a `Requested resource not found` error:

```
Invoking src/handlers/get-all-items.getAllItemsHandler (nodejs12.x)

Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs12.x Docker container image......
Mounting /Users/dev/lab/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/getAllItemsFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: bd1dd37e-d464-13c1-45da-a4d427db1e84 Version: $LATEST
2020-07-12T23:33:50.674Z    bd1dd37e-d464-13c1-45da-a4d427db1e84    INFO    received: { httpMethod: 'GET' }
2020-07-12T23:33:50.812Z    bd1dd37e-d464-13c1-45da-a4d427db1e84    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"ResourceNotFoundException","errorMessage":"Requested resource not found","code":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"Requested resource not found","time":"2020-07-12T23:33:50.809Z","requestId":"E711QAGJJAH7FDFSIU8PR88053VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":26.07018253857256,"stack":["ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found","    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)","    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)","    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)","    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)","    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)","    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)","    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10","    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)","    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)","    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"]}
```

The sample project contains 3 lambda functions that invoke a DynamoDb backend (trimmed for clarity):

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  sam-ap

Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  getAllItemsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/get-all-items.getAllItemsHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A simple example includes a HTTP get method to get all items from a DynamoDB table.
      Policies:
        # Give Create/Read/Update/Delete Permissions to the SampleTable
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref SampleTable
      Environment:
        Variables:
          # Make table name accessible as environment variable from function code during execution
          SAMPLE_TABLE: !Ref SampleTable
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET

  SampleTable:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
    Properties:
      PrimaryKey:
        Name: id
        Type: String
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 2
        WriteCapacityUnits: 2

Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

My assumption is the DynamoDB table isn't created locally inside the AWS test docker container.
Is there another build step or other definition file I'm missing to test DynamoDB locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption is the DynamoDB table isn't created locally inside the AWS test docker container. Is there another build step or other definition file I'm missing to test DynamoDB locally?

That's correct. `sam local invoke` is only for invoking your lambda function locally, not creating a local DynamoDb.

The local DynamoDb should be setup manually, for example using a docker image or java:

- [Install the DynamoDB Docker Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.Docker.html)
- [Deploying DynamoDB Locally on Your Computer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

How to use you local function with local DynamoDb is shown in the AWS blog post and other resources, e.g:

- [New – AWS SAM Local (Beta) – Build and Test Serverless Applications Locally](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-sam-local-beta-build-and-test-serverless-applications-locally/)
- [Develop and test your serverless applications locally with DynamoDB local.](https://github.com/ganshan/sam-dynamodb-local)

Comment: Would you have an idea how to use a different port than 8000 on Mac OS?

The port 8000 supposed to be used by DynamoDB is used by Mac OS (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)

Comment: @SovatthaSok The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) write that you can use `-port` to set new port. Please have a look there for more info.

Comment: Yep thanks, I also noted this param and the DB runs locally successfully. Now unfortunately the lambda function still does not work locally (same error than in the original post). I guess it tries to reach DynamoDB on the port 8000. I did not find out how to change this.

Comment: @SovatthaSok Maybe it would be better to make new question dedicated to this issue with the details of your setup and error messages.

Comment: Yes I understand your point of view. However, I reproduced this issue on my PC with DynamoDB running on port 8000. I am puzzled.